# Using event delegation and getting the object thats linked to the clicked child dom?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to attach an event listener to each `li` element, but instead I want to attach it to the parent `ul`, to avoid confusion, if I remove or add `li` elements.

```
var theParent = document.getElementById("parent-list");
theParent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked item!
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        console.log("li has been clicked, cool!");
        console.log("is this George or Smith!");
    }
});
```

This works fine. However the way I add my li elements to the parent is by creating a custom object, as I need to hold some state information:

```
var Person = function(name, favColor){
  var elem = document.createElement('li');
  theParent.appendChild(elem);
  this.name = name;
  this.color = favColor;

};

var listItems = [];

listItems.push(new Person("Smith", "blue"));
listItems.push(new Person("George", "red"));
```

One of the solutions I was thinking is to add state information to the li elements by using `data-` attribute, but I feel like thats going to get messy If I am going to have so many properties.

Comment: the messy part is creating individual variables for each `person` vs storing in an array or object

Comment: @charlietfl Im storing them in an array, the reason I done it like this is for illustration purposes :)

Comment: well it's a very misleading illustration then. Why would you present it differently? Especially in a question about relationships

Comment: @charlietfl edited my question :) sorry your right.

Comment: so what do you see as being `messy` then? Really not clear what the issue is.

Comment: @charlietfl basically I'm trying to bind the click event to the js object, in this case its the Person object.

Comment: _“basically I'm trying to bind the click event to the js object, in this case its the Person object”_ – that’s kinda nonsense though; the user won’t click on your _JavaScript object_, so “binding the event handler” to it makes little sense. // How about you avoid the “messiness” by using jQuery’s [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead …?

Comment: there are lots of ways to access the data object by reference in array, or as property or attribute of the element. This all sounds like you haven't tried any of them and the question about `data-` attributes being `messy` isn't getting to the root of your problem

Answer (score 1):

right now your JavaScript object and dom elements are not connected at all. you are just using a JavaScript object to create the dom element.
data attribute is a good way to go, you can maybe just have a data attribute with an object index, and save all your objects in a JavaScript array. than on click, retrieve the JavaScript object with the correct index from the array.

Please let me know if this is enough to get you going or you need more.